# JSF Sorting a datatable column throwing error

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am building primefaces data tables dynamically and the datatable code is inside a composite interface. Inside of a loop I call this composite I am using the primefaces columns tag. When I add a `sortBy="#{tblVar[column.name]}"` to the columns tag and I sort then I get the following error

> sortBy="#{tblVar[column.name]}": Property 'documentStatusCode' not found on type org.kheaa.verify.data.VerificationReviewerpf

The part of the error that states Property `documentStatusCode` not found on type is always the same on all the errors, but the type `org.kheaa.verify.data.VerificationReviewerpf` changes depending on which data table you are trying to sort a column on.

The documentStatusCode is a property of the list item for the last data table created. The VerificationReviewerpf is the list item of the data table I am trying to do a sort on.

Even though an error occurs evertime I sort a column the columns still seem to sort correctly. How do I prevent the error from occuring

```
<p:dataTable id="datatable" value="#{cc.attrs.dataTableList}" var="tblVar" paginator="true" rows="10"
    paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,25"
    rowIndexVar="tblIndx" editable="#{cc.attrs.dataTableTemplate.editable}"
    filteredValue="#{cc.filteredList}">

<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{cc.attrs.actionMethodsBean.updateRowAction(tblVar, cc.attrs.dataTableTemplate)}"
        update=":#{cc.message.clientId}"/>

<p:columns id="columns" value="#{cc.attrs.dataTableTemplate.columns}"
    var="column" headerText="#{column.heading}" editable="true"
    filterBy="#{tblVar[column.name]}"
    sortBy="#{tblVar[column.name]}">
```

@Update Each of the datatables created is in it's own accordian panel. The error is occurring when navigating between panels.

Comment: I found that if I set dynamic="false" on the accordian panel I do not get this error anymore. I would like to make dynamic="true" so that all the data is not loaded unless needed. We could have alot of datatables in the accordian panel. Can someone explain why this is happening.

Comment: Does your data-type (across panels/data-sets) always have a property: 'documentStatusCode'? The dynamic vs. static is a hint as to why it is happening, but without a compiled example it isn't obvious to me. I have seen a similar problem on a previous project but without more information on the entities I won't be able to recreate the error quickly.

Comment: Please provide code what the `tblVar` does look like, the relatet entities and the xhtml-part with the accordion.